# Filter Json data when active is true. I'm using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, filter

I have the json:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 10004,
        "PageName": "club",
        "active": "true"
    },
    {
        "Id": 10040,
        "PageName": "qaz",
        "active": "false"
    },
    {
        "Id": 10059,
        "PageName": "jjjjjjj",
        "active": "true"
    }
]
```

Can I filter Json and create new Json data using AngularJS only when "active" is true?
When I click a input button!

Return example:

```
[
    {
        "PageName": "club",
        "active": "true"
    },
    {
        "PageName": "jjjjjjj",
        "active": "true"
    }
]
```

Comment: Write a simple function that iterates of the the object and removes inactive ones.

Comment: Create a plunkr or jsfiddle and I will show you how. You have to use a filter taking 1 arg which is modified on btn click

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module
        .module('some')
        .controller('SomeCtrl', SomeCtrl);

    SomeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function SomeCtrl($scope) {

        $scope.tasks = [
            {
                "Id": 10004,
                "PageName": "club",
                "active": "true"
            },
            {
                "Id": 10040,
                "PageName": "qaz",
                "active": "false"
            },
            {
                "Id": 10059,
                "PageName": "jjjjjjj",
                "active": "true"
            }
        ];

        $scope.filterTask = function () {
            angular.foreach($scope.tasks, function (task, key) {
                if (task.active === false) {
                    $scope.tasks.splice(key, 1);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$filter` inside your controller:

```
$scope.getActiveOnes = function(){
    $scope.activeOnes = $filter('filter')($scope.pages.active, true);
}
```

Now you can bind this function to button with `ng-button` and inside `{{activeOnes}}` you will have active pages or whatever they are